How to use OpenCV to clean up the background of a receipt image after removing the shadows
I have written Python code to remove shadows from a receipt image, but there is still noise caused by the dilation and medianBlur processes around the characters. Are there any algorithms to clean up the background while preserving the characters?
This is my Python code that removes shadows from the receipt image.
import cv2
import pytesseract
import sys
import numpy as np


sys.stdout.reconfigure(encoding='utf-8')
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'

imRGB = cv2.imread(r'D:\Senior-project\images\028.jpg')


split_color_channels = cv2.split(imRGB)
print(split_color_channels)

color_channels_result = []
color_norm_channels_result = []

for color_channel in split_color_channels:

    img_dilation = cv2.dilate(color_channel, np.ones((7,7), np.uint8))

    blur_img = cv2.medianBlur(img_dilation, 21)

    diff_img = 255 - cv2.absdiff(color_channel, blur_img)

    norm_img = cv2.normalize(diff_img,None, alpha=0, beta=255, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
    
    color_channels_result.append(diff_img)
    color_norm_channels_result.append(norm_img)
result = cv2.merge(color_channels_result)`
result_norm = cv2.merge(color_norm_channels_result)
print(result_norm.shape)


cv2.imwrite(r'image.jpg', result_norm)

image = cv2.imread(r'D:\1204314 - Computer Vision and Image Processing\Week1\Lab0101\image.jpg')
print(image.shape)

My original image
This is my receipt image that has had the shadows removed.
I need to clean up the background after the shadow removal process. I have tried using thresholding, but it causes some loss of character information. I need a method to clean up the background while maintaining the completeness and clarity of the characters so that the text can be extracted effectively.

I hope this doesn't sound rude, it's not meant to be. Your result seems worse to me than the original image, it's harder to distinguish the text. Where did you get the idea for this processing?

oh, you need to align the page as well? you didn't say that until now.

follow-up question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78880577/how-can-i-restore-the-characters-in-an-image-to-their-full-clarity-after-using-a

Division normalization is, I believe, a better way to remove the gray background in your image using Python/OpenCV.
Input:

import cv2
import numpy as np

# read the image as grayscale
img = cv2.imread('text_gray_bg.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# blur img
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (0,0), sigmaX=99, sigmaY=99)

# divide img by blur
divide = cv2.divide(img, blur, scale=255)

# save results
cv2.imwrite('text_gray_bg_divide.jpg',divide)

# show results
cv2.imshow("divide", divide)
cv2.waitKey(0)



follow-up question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78880577/how-can-i-restore-the-characters-in-an-image-to-their-full-clarity-after-using-a

Thanks. I posted an answer to that question.

I was hoping you'd vote to close as duplicate. posting the same answer twice, to a duplicate question, does not seem like the right thing. imagine if everyone did that. not a good policy. what do you think?

Right. I will vote to close as duplicate.

Seems that the OP deleted the post to which you linked. So I cannot vote to close it. But yes, that was the proper thing to do. Sorry, I thought you wanted me to post the division normalization to that post.

I have deleted that post. I apologize for the inconvenience.

Why did you delete that post?
